# how to split column by commas using MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

this is my code

```
select top 100
       ih.streetname,
       ih.district,
       ih.intervalhouse
from vw_pn_intervalshouse ih
inner join vw_pn_street s on s.id = ih.streetname
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ih.intervalhouse, ',');
```

i am trying to use string_split but result is incorrect

i will show you some output

```
district        streetname      intervalhouse
32000100001832  1008302496093   1,17
32000100001832  1008302496093   1,17
32000100001832  1008302496095   8,10,12
32000100001832  1008302496095   8,10,12
32000100001832  1008302496095   8,10,12
```

result must be like

```
district        streetname      intervalhouse
32000100001832  1008302496093   1
32000100001832  1008302496093   17
32000100001832  1008302496095   8
32000100001832  1008302496095   10
32000100001832  1008302496095   12
```

what could be the problem? any solutions?

Comment: Can you share your input?

Comment: what do you mean, insert?

Comment: if question is about that i think that interval house is nvarchar

Comment: It also looks like `DISTINCT` might belong somewhere, given that the CSV rows appear to have duplicates.

Comment: Do you really have 2+3 = 5 rows in your table? Or 2?

Comment: Why does the first row still have a delimited value in your expected output?

Comment: which sql server version you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the value column from string_split. You are selecting the column in your table.

```
select top 100
       ih.streetname,
       ih.district,
       s.value
from vw_pn_intervalshouse ih
inner join vw_pn_street s on s.id = ih.streetname
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ih.intervalhouse, ',') s;
```

Comment: now i have new problem,every last row every is empty

Comment: Does your source data have a trailing comma?